# PDF file hosted on S3 is giving "Deceptive site ahead" in bright red

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I have made an s3 bucket on AWS and am hosting pdf files in it so that public pdf urls can be used in whatsapp message. After uploading the pdf file, clicking on the s3 url gives a bright red [Deceptive Site Ahead](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/security/social-engineering) warning indicating phishing, when we just want the user to access these links anywhere. This happens when a user is logged in into chrome. In case of incognito chrome, it works perfectly fine.

Could anyone guide me on what S3 changes need to be done so that these pdf urls could be opened anywhere without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue via using the **S3 Object URL** instead of using **S3 URL**

Below are the examples for both of the urls —

### Object URL

```
 http(s)://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/object
```

### S3 URL

```
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/path/to/object
```